# Netherlands visa and bank statement

Tags: schengen-visas, netherlands, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am a student in UK and planning to travel Netherlands this coming February. Problem is, I have two bank account, one is everyday banking and the other one is saving account. I could print out the everyday bank account, but I couldn't print out the saving because I made it four months ago and it is annual account. In the main account (everyday bank), I have all the records that I received money and moved them to saving, and I printed out the transaction record for the saving account. (not statement)
If I have all the records that I have moved money from my main account to saving, and if I have evidence, will it be okay with visa?
Apparently I have more than 1000 pounds in my saving account, (for two months long) and I don't have money in my main account. (Usually I move money from saving to main whenever needed)

Comment: Are you sure you can't get a statement for your savings account? You might need to phone your bank or visit a branch.

Comment: I went to the bank but they told me since I made an annual saving account, I can print it out next year, or I need to apply for it and wait for 4-5 day but I have appointment next day. so I printed out the transaction for saving account

Comment: Is it a requirement from the Schengen visa application to show bank statements? I remember such from UK visa application but not for the Schengen one.

Comment: yes it is. and I need curtain amount of money in my bank account so I can prove that I can travel Schengen area. I do have money in my saving, but not in main account

Comment: In my main account statement, it shows both saving and main account (amount of money), but it only shows the main account "statement". And I couldn't print out the saving account statement because it's annual.